Docker container healthcheck status as a prometheus metric?
I want to get information about docker container healthcheck current status ("healthy" or "unhealthy") into my Prometheus, so I could draw container status graphs in grafana, send alerts when container comes unhealthy with alertmanager, etc.
Built-in dockerd prometheus endpoint doesn't provides healthcheck metrics for containers, cadvisor (which is sometimes used to gain some additional metrics about containers) doesn't either.
What is the correct way to get prometheus metrics for docker healthcheck results?

I suspect it will be necessary to roll your own Prometheus Exporter to accomplish this. Are you sure you need to capture the data in Prometheus, or could you directly display the data in whatever reporting platform like Grafana?
